# Free WYSIWYG Markdown editor

Tags: software-recommendation, text-editor, open-source, markdown

I've been using Typora as a Markdown editor when it was free (during beta), but now it's pay for use and I want to find an equivalent, free (preferably open source) tool.

**My requirements**:

- free (preferably open source)
- rather than a separate editing and preview pane, I want the editing to happen in the same pane in which the  Markdown code is rendered, i.e., WYSIWYG. This is what Typora does
- support for drawing tables, bulleted/numbered lists, code fences, import images, etc. Basically, the same features as the post editor on Stack Exchange, but WYSIWYG instead of separate editing/preview panes
- rendering of math formulas
- runs on Monterey

**Research**: I googled around a bit and I found the following;

- [Mou app](http://mouapp.com/) seemed to have been widely recommended in the past, but it's not being developed anymore (and anyway it cannot be downloaded, since the site is down)
- [MacDown](https://macdown.uranusjr.com/) is active, but it has separated editing and rendering panes
- similarly for [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown)

Comment: You mean you don't want to have to pay for it, not that it's free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Marktext](https://github.com/marktext/marktext), a open source markdown editor.

Support:

- Realtime preview (WYSIWYG) and a clean and simple interface to get a distraction-free writing experience.
- Support CommonMark Spec, GitHub Flavored Markdown Spec and selective support Pandoc markdown.
- Markdown extensions such as math expressions (KaTeX), front matter and emojis.
- Support paragraphs and inline style shortcuts to improve your writing efficiency.
- Output HTML and PDF files.
- Various themes: Cadmium Light, Material Dark etc.
- Various editing modes: Source Code mode, Typewriter mode, Focus mode.
- Paste images directly from clipboard.